# Reinstall drivers ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, apt, package-management

Accidentaly, I uninstalled the networking drivers (I guess). I tried to uninstall a package this way:

```
sudo apt-get remove rpm*
```

I installed rpm to install a rpm file, that didn't work, so I wanted to remove it. I searched on google how to remove completely a package with apt, and I read that was the way to uninstall completely the package. Silly of me, I didn't investigate first, so now I know that command line is for remove all de binaries with the string `rp`, and now I guess that I removed the network driver, whose name starts with `rp` or some like that.

Now, the wireless doesn't appear and I can't connect to internet, even with a ethernet cable connected.

How can reinstall those drivers?

Comment: did you install those network drivers yourself with apt? Otherwise if they were included, you can't really uninstall them (without completely uninstalling the kernel)

Comment: No, I didn't. That erased something that I need to connect to internet, because after that, I can't. No wifi, and with the ethernet cable, still without internet.

Comment: Posting the contents of `/var/log/apt/term.log` and `/var/log/dpkg.log` on pastebin and linking them in your question will probably help people to figure out what happened.

Comment: You just have solved my problem. I looked for the term.log and I saw something, that command line erased all the packages that had the character 'rpm', and uninstalled others packages too. I downloaded them and I will install them with dpkg.